# Как ввести массив с клавиатуры?

Tags: python

Как вводить элементы массива с клавиатуры? Задание: Дан массив целых чисел. Найти сумму и произведение элементов массива, расположенных между первым и вторым нулевыми элементами.

```
l = [1, 4, 0, 3, 2, 7, 3, 1, 0, 34]
t, c, k = 1, 0, 0
for i in l:
  if i == 0:
     if k == 1: break
     k = 1
     continue
  if k == 1:
     t *= i
     c += i

print(t)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ввод чисел через пробел:

```py
my_list = [int(el) for el in input().split()]
```

Первый и второй ноль можно найти через index (проверка на вхождение обоих нулей - count(0)):

```py
first = my_list.index(0)
second = my_list.index(0, first + 1)
```

Сумма:

```py
s = sum(q[first+1:second])
```

Произведение:

```py
from functools import reduce
mul = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, q[first+1:second])
```